# Getting error in scheme "The object (unquote f), passed as an argument to identifier->symbol, is not an identifier."

Tags: lambda, functional-programming, scheme, function-composition, mit-scheme

I am trying to implement a function `composex` that given a list of functions `funcs` returns a function that is a composition of all functions in `funcs`
So,

> input -> [f1 f2 f3 ...]
>   output -> f'(x) = f1(f2(f3( ... (x))))

The code snippet I have is:

```
(define (reducex initial f arr)
  (if (null? arr)
    initial
    (reducex (f initial (car arr))
      f
      (cdr arr)
    )
  )
)


(define (abst x)
  (if (< x 0)
    (- x)
    x
  )
)

(define (mult2 x)
  (* x 2))

(define (composex funcs)
  (lambda (x)
    (reducex '()
      (lambda (ini, f) (f x))
      funcs)
  )
)

(define absmult2 (composex (cons abst (cons mult2 '()))))
(absmult2 2)
(absmult2 -2)
```

The error I get is in `composex`

```
;The object (unquote f), passed as an argument to identifier->symbol, is not an identifier.
;To continue, call RESTART with an option number:
; (RESTART 1) => Return to read-eval-print level 1.
```

I am using mit-scheme for execution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy fix, IIUC: you put a comma in the parameter list for your inner `lambda`. Take it out.

Comma has a special meaning in Scheme; it allows you to "escape" from a quasiquote. In this case, you're not using quasiquote, so a comma here doesn't make any sense in Scheme.

This is a pretty terrible error message, though.

Comment: The error message is what tripped me actually. Google wasn't helping too with this error message.

Answer (score 3):

**lurking problems**

As @John noted, you need to remove the `,` in `(ini, f)` and change to `(ini f)`. This yields a syntactically correct program, but other issues persist.

I would recommend changes to your `compose` procedure. One, the initial `'()` is wrong because it doesn't match the type of a function. You get a strange result if you try to apply an argument to an empty composition

```
(define (composex funcs)
  (lambda (x)
    (reducex '()
             (lambda (ini f) (f x))
             funcs)))

(define foo (composex '()))
(foo 'x) ; => '()
```

Second, your reducer `(lambda (ini f) (f x))` is incorrect so you're getting incorrect answers

```
(absmult2 2) ; 4
(absmult2 -2) ; -4
```

This is because your reducer ignores `ini`. This is effectively what is happening when we call `(absmult2 -2)`

```
(let ((ini '()))
  (set! ini (abst -2))
  (set! ini (mult2 -2))
  ini) ;; -4
```

The behaviour we actually want is

```
(let ((ini -2))
  (set! ini (abst ini))
  (set! ini (mult2 ini))
  ini) ;; 4
```

We can fix these two issues simultaneously by reworking `composex`

```
(define (composex funcs)
  (lambda (ini)
    (reducex ini
             (lambda (x f) (f x))
             funcs)))

(absmult2 2) ; 4
(absmult2 -2) ; 4
```

It also works for empty compositions now

```
(define foo (composex '()))
(foo 'z) ; 'z
```

---

**helping yourself**

Ironically, the mistake you made originally can be used elsewhere to improve the readability of your code. You can use the unquoting comma `,` instead of `cons` to define your composition. Note the use of [quasiquote](http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-ref/Quoting.html) `` ` ``

```
(define absmult2 (composex `(,abst ,mult2)))

(absmult2 2)  ; 4
(absmult2 -2) ; 4
```

Alternatively, you could change `composex` so that it accepts a variable amount of inputs

```
(define (composex . funcs)
  (lambda (ini)
    (reducex ini
             (lambda (x f) (f x))
             funcs)))

(define absmult2 (composex abst mult2))

(absmult2 2)  ; 4
(absmult2 -2) ; 4
```

---

**lateral thinking**

Consider these other implementations of `composex` as a way of tickling your brain

```
(define (composex . fs)
  ;; simplified composition of two functions
  (define (comp f g)
    (lambda (x) (g (f x))))
  ;; results in simplified reduce
  (reducex identity comp fs))

(define absmult2 (composex abst mult2))

(absmult2 2)  ; 4
(absmult2 -2) ; 4
```

Above, how does this `composex` handle the empty composition example we talked about?

And one that doesn't even use `reduce` – Notice this last one prevents the programmer from creating an empty composition

```
(define (composex f . fs)
  (lambda (x)
    (if (null? fs)
        (f x)
        ((apply composex fs) (f x)))))

(define absmult2 (composex abst mult2))

(absmult2 2)  ; 4
(absmult2 -2) ; 4
```

Comment: Thank you for such a nice and detailed answer. After checking the first answer, this is exactly what I was fixing in my code before coming back here.

Comment: @AyushGoel you're welcome. I made some additional comments. I hope you have a wonderful time learning one of the best languages ever created. Let us know if you need more help :)

Comment: I like the two expositions with the `set!` - the first showing the Reader and the second - State monad's computation model (no change vs the change). the OP's *text* seems to indicate the intended direction of composition being the usual right-to-left though. the last `composex` could be tweaked to accommodate that, and also allow for the empty composition: ``(composex . fs) | null? fs = (\x.x) | null? (cdr fs) = (car fs) | else = (\x.(f (`(composex . ,(cdr fs)) x)))``. the remaining question is, how could the left-to-right `reducex` be used to make the right-to-left composition?

Answer (score 1):

In this part:

```scm
(lambda (ini, f) (f x))
```

Now I'm not sure if you by mistake have separated the arguments by `,` or by some crazy coincident wanted `ini,` to be the name of the parameter, but `,` is used in quasiquote expressions:

```scm
(define a 10)
(define b 20)
`(list with ,a and ,(+ a b) inserted) 
; ==> (list with 10 and 30 inserted)
```

Just like `'` these are handled by reader macros. Thus just like `'x` is `(quote x)`, `` `(,x) `` is the same as `(quasiquote ((unquote x)))` and `quote`, `quoasiquote` and `unquote` are special forms.  Your lamba ends up looking like:

```scm
(lambda (ini (unquote f)) (f x))
```

MIT Scheme doesn't support optional arguments only symbols like `ini` and `f` can be in the lamba list and not a list `(unquote f)`. Thus you need to change it to:

```scm
(lambda (ini f) (f x))
```

**EDIT**

Your `reducex` is the same as `foldl` except for the order of arguments in it and the function it takes. eg.

```scm
(fold cons '() '(1 2 3))    ; ==> (3 2 1)
(reducex '() (lambda (a e) (cons e a)) '(1 2 3)) ; ==> (3 2 1)
```

Your `compose` does the application in the wrong order and it's common for such function to take a variable number of arguments. eg.

```scm
((compose - +) 3 5)
; ==> -8
```

Here is what I think you need to do:

```scm
(define (compose . funcs)
  (case (length funcs)
    ((0) (lambda (v) v)) ; identity
    ((1) (car funcs))    ; return the argument
    (else                ; return a composition
     (let* ((rfuncs (reverse funcs))
            (initial-func (car rfuncs))
            (rest-funcs (cdr rfuncs))
            (reduce (lambda (fn a) (fn a))))
       (lambda args
         (foldl reduce
                (apply initial-func args)
                rest-funcs))))))
```

So lets test it with something where order matters:

```scm
(define (add100 v) (+ v 100))
(define (double v) (* v 2))

(define (manual-compose v)
  (double (add100 v)))

(define test-compose (compose double add100))

(manual-compose 50)
; ==> 300
(test-compose 50)
; ==> 300
```

If composition were done in the order of your `composex` the answwer would have been `200`. `compose` supports the arity of the right most function, thus the one to be applied first. If it's a  thunk then the resulting function is ok with zero arguments and with multiple arity one it becomes a multi arity function:

```scm
(define double+ (compose double +))
(double+ 3 8 9 2)
; ==> 44
```

Comment: Nice explanation of `quote` and `unquote`. Although syntactically correct, `(lambda (ini f) (f x))` has other unseen problems – details in my answer :D

Comment: MIT Scheme does support optional arguments; there seems to be no way to specify their default values though, which is probably what you meant. /not-a-nitpick :)

Comment: @WillNess There is a difference between rest arguments and optional arguments.

Comment: indeed, [the documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-ref/Lambda-Expressions.html#Lambda-Expressions) talks of both.